# How to deal with variations of "How to merge some text with some custom format?"

Tags: discussion

There are literally an infinite number of custom formats anyone could come up with. But inserting a string (or a set of strings) into *any* such format usually boils down to one of two things:

- Insert after some index, literal or regex.
- Insert before some index, literal or regex.

Rather than ending up with a massive heap of very similar answers to what is only superficially different questions (because of the custom format), should we generalize questions so that every single "How to insert a string at [index, literal or regex]" can be closed as a duplicate of a small set of well-curated Qs&As? Maybe people are already doing this, but it's difficult to find them because the search terms are so general?

Comment: This type of scenario is exactly why we need to come up with more granular close reasons.

Comment: I guess you can always write a really thorough self-answer and start using it as a dupe target. Although, I realise it's probably easier said than done - I've been debating doing this for some other types of questions I frequently see but I've not done it yet. Problem is that I want it to be really good but then it seems to also become a bit too broad. Or I'm just feeling lazy at other times...